# Memory stacks with multiple users or is it somehow unique?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

For example my script would use 1gb RAM everytime function is launched and knowing that there is a 2GB cap for .NET, does it mean that if three users launch same function at exact same time it will go to 3gb RAM usage and will throw an system out of memory error? Or how does it work?

Comment: The 2GB limit is per process (application) and only if you're running in 32 bit mode. So this would only happen if your process is 32 bit, and every user calls the function in the same process (some shared process, or a server process or whatever)

Comment: @DavidLibido So in my example it would throw an error with three users?

Comment: That depends, would all user start their own "application"? Then no.

Comment: @DavidLibido Not sure if I understand what do you mean with starting their own application? I mean just launching a function on website with a button that consumes quite amount of memory usage.

Comment: You never mentioned you were talking about a website. If it's a website, then every time the function is launched it will run in one process (the process hosting the website), so if this process is running in 32 bit mode it could be an issue.

Comment: @DavidLibido So it all depends on the hosting? Sorry for too many questions, I just couldn't really find enough info, that is why I came here q_ q

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming it will be hosted on IIS. Default settings are usually to run in 64 bit mode, but it may depend on your hosting provider.